# remote desktop with ip like 192.168.0.23 from outside the office

Tags: windows-10, remote-access, mstsc

I would like to reach my computer from outside the office.

The computer has a local ip like 192.168.0.23

What can I do to reach my computer from outside please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

R-click on my computer, then properties, on the right pannel click remote settings, then from the new window check if the option "Allow Remote Assistanse ....." is checked, then you can use Remote Desktop connection to solve your problem ! 
Or a simpler solution is to use Team Viewer software ... much much preferred 
good luck